# Order of the center of $Sym(n)$

Tags: symmetric-groups

With the standard notations, what's $|Z(Sym(n))|$ equal to, in terms of $n$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913317/prove-that-the-symmetric-group-s-n-n-geq-3-has-trivial-center).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does $Sym(n)$ mean the symmetric group $S_n$?

$S_2$ is Abelian, but all other $S_n$ have trivial centre.

Comment: Ok, clear. I came across this question while arguing whether it could make sense to apply the conjugacy class equation to $Sym(n)$.