# Prove $D_{12}$ and $S_4$ are not isomorphic groups in 3 different ways

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

Give three reasons why $D_{12}$ and $S_{4}$ are not isomorphic. More precisely, prove that $D_{12}$  and every group isomorphic to it satisfy three properties that $S_{4}$ does not satisfy.

So I have proved that $D_{12}$ has an element of order $12$ and that $S_{4}$ does not. I am hoping to prove that there are a different number of elements of one order than in the other group but I don't know what else to do because neither are cyclic or abelian and the groups both have the same order.

Please help

Comment: Good observation about the elements of order 12. What about the number of elements of other orders?

Comment: @CalvinLin so there are 6 elements of order 4 in $S_{4}$ and only 2 elements of order 4 in $D_{12}$

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps : could be enough to note that $D_{12} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{12} \rtimes_{\psi}\mathbb{Z}_2$ where $\psi$ is the inversion and $S_4 \simeq A_4 \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\varphi$ is the conjugancy by a transposition

Comment: hmm I don't think we have learned that yet so I don't think I can use that. but thank you!

Comment: @Allie I'm sorry, you could edit your question to specify what's usable in order to avoid answers like mine

Comment: no worries! I appreciate the response

Answer (score 0):

One property is that $S_4$ has trivial center, but $D_{12}$ has not.

References:

[Prove that the symmetric group $S_n$, $n \geq 3$, has trivial center.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913317/prove-that-the-symmetric-group-s-n-n-geq-3-has-trivial-center/913359)

[Center of dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469131/center-of-dihedral-group)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the element of order twelve in $D_{12}$ is one way to do this.

Two others include:

- $D_{12}$ has the derived subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$, whereas $S_4$ has derived subgroup isomorphic to $A_4$.
- $D_{12}$ has nine normal subgroups, whereas $S_4$ has four.